# Showing that $|\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\ln(1+\sum_i a_i(n)^n)|=O(n \ln(2))$?

Tags: limits, inequality, logarithms

I am wanting to prove that

$$\left|\ln\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^{2^n-1} (a_i(n))^n\right)\right|= O(n \ln(2))$$
where $a_i(n)$ are functions of $n\in \Bbb{Z}$ bounded such that $|a_i(n)|\lt 1\; \forall n$. The prove is trivial if we know that $a_i(n) \gt 0$ since then $1\le 1+\sum_i (a_i(n))^n \le2^n$. But how would I go about proving it for where in general $a_i(n)$ can be negative (if it is indeed true)?

Comment: You're taking a *limit* of $n$ on the left hand side of the inequality, so what is the $n$ doing on the right hand side?

Comment: @BarryCipra I mean that in the limit of large $n$ the LHS is less then the RHS. I will edit to clarify

Comment: You could probably sharpen it by asking if $\lim_{n\to\infty}({1\over n}\ln(1+ etc.))\le\ln2$.